# Does "total of all the" make sense?

Tags: nouns

> The sum of all the numbers from 1 to 10 is 55.

Can the "sum" in the sentence above be replaced with "total" as follows?

> The total of all the numbers from 1 to 10 is 55.

I found the phrase "total of all the..."  on the Internet, but I became afraid whether this usage is correct after looking up dictionary definitions for "total" although I cannot explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "total", but using "sum" is clearer in a mathematical context where "sum" means "the result of adding".

"Total" is useful when counting money or frequencies, or in a context where "sum" could be misunderstood as "calculation".

Comment: Then, to be confusing, we also have the [*sum total*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sum%20total) . . .

Answer (score 1):

"Sum" and "total" are synonyms if used to mean "the amount resulting from the addition of two or more numbers, amounts, or items".

[Sum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sum)

[Total](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/total)

Comment: Not quite. _Sum_ specifies a result of addition, whereas _total_ simply specifies a result of some operation, which could be addition, but could also be subtraction or multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO sum is addition of things (that are related to numbers) and total is collection in entirety or aggregation of (concepts, data) that are not necessarily countable.